# Можно ли получить результат там, где был вызван AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Когда вызывается АsynsTask, результат из `doInBackground` приходит в `OnPostExecute`. Можно ли получить результат там, где был вызван AsyncTask?

Comment: нет, нельзя. На то он и *Async*Task, что выполняется ассинхронно.

Answer (score 1):

Не слушай окаянных, результат еще как можно получить используя интерфейс

Ты можешь создать интерфейс в классе AsyncTask и потом вызвать его в onPostExecute()

Пример:

Твой интерфейс:

```
public interface OnTaskCompleted{
    void onTaskCompleted();
}
```

В Activity прописываешь **implements OnTaskCompleted** Activity выдаст ошибку что не хватает метода авто исправление само добавит метод, YourAsyncTask(this) указываешь куда будет вызван результат выполнения потока в данном случае **this** т.е Activity:

```
public YourActivity implements OnTaskCompleted{
    // your Activity
    new YourAsyncTask(this).execute();
}
```

В AsyncTask в конструкторе присваиваешь listener:

```
public YourTask extends AsyncTask<Object,Object,Object>{ //change Object to required type
    private OnTaskCompleted listener;

public interface OnTaskCompleted{
    void onTaskCompleted();
}

    public YourTask(OnTaskCompleted listener){
        this.listener=listener;
    }

    // required methods

    protected void onPostExecute(Object o){
        // your stuff
        listener.onTaskCompleted();
    }
}
```

В Основном Activity появится метод onTaskCompleted там ты сможешь просмотреть результат выполнения.

[Ссылка на оригинал](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963691/android-asynctask-sending-callbacks-to-ui)

Answer (score 0):

Можно вызвать у экземпляра AsyncTask'a метод `get()` и получить результат, но это заблокирует поток, в котором он был вызван до того момента, пока задача не выполнится. В этом случае смысла от AsyncTask'a будет не особо много. По этому у него есть метод `onPostExecute()` который вызывается в UI потоке и в котором необходимо обрабатывать результат выполнения.

Comment: А если я создам глобальный массив в него запишу результат а после его заберу в нужном мне месте. Это плохая реализация.

Comment: @user186301 так конечно можно сделать, но зачем эти лишние телодвижения. Опишите более подробно вашу задачу, что бы сформулировать более подробный ответ.

Comment: Вообщем есть Активити. В нем AsynsTask который загружает данные из интернета и передаёт адаптеру. Также там реализована подгрузка списка, шапка и многое другое. Дело в том, что при нажатии на пункт списка. Он должен пересоздатся с другими данными(т.е. все тоже только другие данные, для этого AsynsTask принимает на вход параметр, который это определяет). Дело в том, что нажатия на пункт ловятся в адаптере(отдельном классе) И вопрос. Как от туда можно пересоздать список?

Comment: @user186301 можно воспользоваться чем то типа EventBus(https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) что бы высылать события для перезагрузки списка. И все равно непонятно в чем проблема, дергайте ```AsyncTask``` и в его ```onPostExecute``` обновляйте список.